# EditorTemplate for "Floats" not being called in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a property of type "float" in my ViewModel. It's being displayed as a TextBox with a default value of "0".

I added an "EditorTemplates" folder inside the "Shared" folder & created a new "Float.cshtml" file with the following content:

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue == 0 ? "" : ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "text-box single-line" })
```

However, still when I run the application, float fields are still being displayed with a default value of 0.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I am just trying to see how ASP.NET reacts to custom templates, till now, the engine is not processing my custom template, something similar to:

```
LatLng.cshtml

@model float
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "text-box single-line "}) Latitude
```

On the ViewModel,

```
    [UIHint("LatLng")]
    public float? Latitude { get; set; }
```

On the View,

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Latitude)
```

Nothing is changing, default template is being used.

Comment: You don't show how you're adding the editor to your form/markup. Are you using `Html.EditorFor()`?

Answer (score 5):

Float is not actually a .NET type, it's a C# type.  Float maps to System.Single, so you need to create a Single.cshtml and not a Float.cshtml.

You can also get around this by specifying a UIHint attribute on the model data, or by specifying the template to use in your Editor or EditorFor methods.

Comment: Is it normal when the Textbox shown on screen that it contains value 0? Also, Im very new to templates, what's the idea behind them, how to work with them? Thanks

Comment: Yes, numeric textboxes always display a 0 by default. Templates are basically MVC's version of a user control, they allow you to create a custom display for any type you like.

Comment: @bhaidar - If it contains a 0, it will display a 0.  Yeah, it's normal that it displays whatever value is in the data item.

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround is if you just set ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue to return a string in the model, so you don't have to do that weird logic on the view. If you need it to post back a new value (for editing purposes), you just have to add some logic in the controller to turn the string back into a float.